# Use multiple where Clause in INERT INTO statement- mysql

Tags: php, mysql

The below query works perfectly and inserts rows based on the condition

```
INSERT INTO (t1.userid,t1.name,t1.email,t1.phone) SELECT 
t2.userid,t2.name,t2.email,t2.phone FROM t2 where t2.name!='';
```

But ,the below query inserts 0 rows and does not throw any error too. With the use of multiple where conditions,the query is not working

```
INSERT INTO (t1.userid,t1.name,t1.email,t1.phone) SELECT 
t2.userid,t2.name,t2.email,t2.phone FROM t2 where (t2.name!='' AND t2.name!=0 AND
 t2.name!=NULL)
```

Comment: Have you tried to select the values without the `Select`? Because I don't think there is anything wrong with the insert, there is just no records to insert.

Comment: Does MySQL allow "t2.name!='' AND t2.name!=0", i.e. comparing with either a string or a number??? Looks invalid to me.

Comment: you cannot use INSERT INTO value WHERE statement;

Comment: @Jaques There are values in that table. As I told you, the first query retrieves result but the second does not

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are doing a null comparison wrongly and you should be using `not null`

Here is an example

```
mysql> select * from test ;
+------+------+
| id   | val  |
+------+------+
|    1 | NULL |
|    2 |      |
|    3 | 0    |
|    4 | aa   |
|    5 | cc   |
+------+------+
5 rows in set (0.00 sec

mysql> select * from test where val != '' and val != '0' and val != null;
Empty set (0.00 sec)


mysql> select * from test where val != '' and val != '0' and val is not null;
+------+------+
| id   | val  |
+------+------+
|    4 | aa   |
|    5 | cc   |
+------+------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)


mysql> select null != null ;
+--------------+
| null != null |
+--------------+
|         NULL |
+--------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select null is not null ;
+------------------+
| null is not null |
+------------------+
|                0 |
+------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select null is  null ;
+---------------+
| null is  null |
+---------------+
|             1 |
+---------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

So in your case it would be

```
INSERT INTO (t1.userid,t1.name,t1.email,t1.phone) 
SELECT 
 t2.userid,t2.name,t2.email,t2.phone FROM t2 where (
 t2.name!='' 
 AND t2.name!='0' 
 AND t2.name is not NULL
)
```

Comment: @user2401175 Like I said, the `Select` statement did not return values. I know the first one did, but the second query did not return values, hence no error and no records. If things like this happen, it is always best to run the statement without the insert to see if you actually get values back

Answer (score 1):

to check NULL in mysql you use `IS NULL` keyword and `IS NOT NULL`

so your where condition is :=

```
where (t2.name!='' AND t2.name!=0 AND
 t2.name IS NOT NULL);
```